# How can I create an array from an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, prototype

I am learning about array-like objects in JavaScript, and I'm trying to figure out what the essential difference between `Array` and `Object` is. So I thought, if I make an object and set its properties to be the same as an array, will the result of `Array.isArray(obj)` become true? I did this:

```js
let obj = Object.create(Array.prototype);
let arr = [];
Object.defineProperty(obj, "length", {
  value: 0,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false
});
console.log(Array.isArray(obj)); //false
```

I think I copied the `__proto__` and properties correctly, but the result is `false`. The problem also appears when I use a `for...of` loop.

So, what is the difference between `obj` and `arr`, and can I alter `obj` to make `Array.isArray(obj)` be true?

Comment: try `Object.create(Array.protoype, { constructor: { value: Array } })`. you can add the `length` definition to the object in the second argument too, if you wanted

Comment: Not sure you can transform an object into an array. [`Array.isArray`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.isarray) should directly call the [`IsArray`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isarray) abstract operation which, in turn, directly checks if the argument is an array. So, it shouldn't duck-type.

Comment: You can make an object [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) so it can be used in `for...of` loops and such, but arrays and objects are fundamentally different things. Arrays are ordered lists of values, while objects are mappings of keys to values. And yes, I know, arrays _are_ objects in that they have Object.prototype in their prototype chain, but they have a distinct purpose.